# Tracking launchtl locate database creation

Tags: macos, launchctl, locate

I'm running the `locate` command to look for a file on MacOS and I get a warning that `locate.database` needs to be created with a certain command. I noticed it takes quite a while to build the database through `launchctl` -- Is there a way to track the progress of the command?

Here is the CLI snippet:

```
cjs-MBP15:auth_armistice cj$ locate /CoreServices.h

WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.
```